# Mongoldb-Casbah: get first match in a collection

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I am using Scala and Mongoldb-Casbah and I get some data with:

```
val myData: Traversable[Imports.DBObject] = myCollection.find(query).toTraversable
```

The data returned are a collection like this:

[
 { _id:"...", 
   prices:[
           {myValue:"...",...},
           {myValue:"...",...},...
          ]
 },
 {...
 },...
]

What I need to get, it is the first not empty `myValue`.

I tried different things like:

```
myData.foldLeft(List[Any]()) { (acc, v) =>
      acc ++ v.get("prices").asInstanceOf[BasicDBList].filter(_.asInstanceOf[DBObject].getOrElse("myValue", "").toString.nonEmpty).take(1)
    }
```

but it is not returning one single value unless I make it even more complicated. I didn't tried `findMap` or `collectFirst` yet tho.

Any idea how to extract one single `myValue` from that data?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have documents like below:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId(...),
  "item": "A",
  "prices": [ {},{"myValue": 1}, {"myValue": 4}, {} ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId(...),
  "item": "B",
  "prices": [ {"myValue": 7}, {}, {"myValue": 9}, {} ]
}
```

If you would like to extract one single `myValue` element that is not empty, you could utilise [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator. The `$elemMatch` operator limits the contents of an array field from the query results to contain only the *first* element matching the `$elemMatch` condition.

As an example to do this in scala/casbah:

```
val coll = MongoClient()("dbName")("collName")

/*  The query below is equivalent to db mongo shell 
    db.collName.find({item:"A"}, {prices: { $elemMatch: { myValue: {$exists:true} } } } ) */

val elemMatch = "prices" $elemMatch MongoDBObject("myValue"-> MongoDBObject("$exists" -> true))
val query = MongoDBObject("item" -> "A")

coll.find(query, elemMatch).foreach { doc =>
    println(doc)
}
// Output: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "..."} , "prices" : [ { "myValue" : 1.0} ] }
```

The above was tested with : MongoDB v3.2, Scala v2.11.7, Casbah v3.1.0.